# Container has its size restrained when using with BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, scroll, bottomnavigationview

I have a screen that is applied with BottomNavigationBar. With the index = 0, it will lead to home.dart.

Inside home.dart, I want to have to a column of Widgets. It contains 2 titles(put in Row widgets) and 2 listViews. The 1st ListView I want it to scroll horizontally, and the 2nd one vertical. Both ListView is scrollable. However, it seems that both lists(or containers) are restrained in size somehow, because the 2nd ListView scroll behavior is that it only scroll inside the bottom half of the screen, not the whole screen.

I thought of adding a SingleChildScrollView with Expanded outside the whole Container in home.dart. But it return the error

mainScreen.dart

```
int _currentTab = 0;
void onTabTapped(int tabNumber) {
    setState(() {
      _currentTab = tabNumber;
    });
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.setState(() {
      contents = [
        HomeTab(),
        DownloadedTab(),
        SettingTab()
      ];
    });
  }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: contents != null ? contents[_currentTab] : Text("Page is loaded"),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          backgroundColor: Theme.ColorsMode.appBarGradientStart,
          currentIndex: _currentTab,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
              title: new Text('Home')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.file_download),
              title: new Text('Download')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.settings),
              title: new Text('Setting')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

home.dart

```
@override
Widget build(Build context) {
  return Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Course', textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              // height: 6000.0,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: (showInHomeClass != null && showInHomeClass != null) ? showInHomeClass.length : 0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Card(
                          child: Center (
                            child: Image.network('https://example.com'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('News', textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              // height: 6000.0,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: (showInHomeClass != null && showInHomeClass != null) ? showInHomeClass.length : 0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Card(
                          child: Center (
                            child: Image.network('https://example.com'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              ),
            ),
          )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

error when adding SingleChildScrollView and Expanded

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Listener:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1786 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was
    SingleChildScrollView 
lib\…\Home\Home.dart:115
#4      Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3176
#5      Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
#6      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5445
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 6 of 675 libraries in 919ms.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1786 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    SingleChildScrollView
```

Any suggestions?